# how to get image from pdf using pdfbox in c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, pdfbox

how to get image from pdf using pdfbox in c# .net.
All the answer about this question are posted in java language.
No one post correct answer in c# language in what I've seen.

I'm tried the java code in c# but some methods are not working in c#.

I want to extract image from pdf file using pdfbox in c# .net

Comment: C# is not supported, IKVM has been discontinued, so you'll have a hard time if you insist on using C#. It is possible that the "not working" methods are from PDFBox 2.0.*, and that your PDFBox version is from 1.8.

Comment: hi @TilmanHausherr can you please find the following answer.
It's working fine I got the image from the pdf

Comment: I can't test it, but I think this can work for simple files. (what's missing here is patterns and inline images, but that is very advanced stuff)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the answer.

Extend the class in your class PDFStreamEngine

Example:

```
public class ImageExtraction : PDFStreamEngine
{
    int i=1;
    public void GetImageFromPDF(string fileName)
    {
        PDDocument pDDocument = PDDocument.load(new java.io.File(fileName));
        PDPage page = new PDPage();
        page = pDDocument.getPages().get(0);
        ImageExtraction obj = new ImageExtraction();
        processPage(page);
    }

    protected override void processOperator(Operator @operator, java.util.List operands)
    {
        string operation = @operator.getName();
        if (operation == "Do")
        {
            PDDocument pDDocument = new PDDocument();
            org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSName objectName = (org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSName)operands.get(0);
            org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.PDXObject xobject = getResources().getXObject(objectName);
            org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject pDImageXObject = new org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject(pDDocument);
            org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.form.PDFormXObject pDFormXObject = new org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.form.PDFormXObject(pDDocument);
            if (xobject.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(pDImageXObject.GetType()))
            {
                org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject image = (org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject)xobject;
                int imageWidth = image.getWidth();
                int imageHeight = image.getHeight();
                // same image to local
                java.awt.image.BufferedImage bImage = new java.awt.image.BufferedImage(imageWidth, 
                        imageHeight, java.awt.image.BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                bImage = image.getImage();
                javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(bImage, "PNG", new java.io.File(imageFolderPath + "image_" + i + ".png"));
                i++;
                Console.WriteLine("Image saved.");
            }
            else if (xobject.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(pDFormXObject.GetType()))
            {
                org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.form.PDFormXObject form = (org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.form.PDFormXObject)xobject;
                showForm(form);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is Java, isnt'it?

Comment: This code is not a java this is c#.
I have added the PDFBox dll

Answer (score 0):

Looks like someone started a dotnet port of pdfbox.

https://github.com/UglyToad/PdfPig